# fancybox different styles for different images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm wanting to control just SOME of the images in my fancybox group.

This is related to another question I've asked in this area but is moving on to a different part of the problem, and so I've started a new question.

Given the code

```
<div id="gallery"> 
    <a href="photos/pic1.jpg" rel="lightbox-left" title=""> 
        <img src="photos/pic1_2.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="photos/pic2.jpg" rel="lightbox-left" title="my title" class="flag"> 
        <img src="photos/pic2_2.jpg"  /></a>
</div>
```

you'll see that the 'a' tag containing second image (pic2.jpg) has a class of 'flag'.  This is because I want it to be styled differently from the other one.  Let's say, for example, that I want it to have a green background.

I can achieve that for all instances with something like

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background-color: green;
}
```

but that applies to ALL the displayed pictures.  Clearly my class of 'flag' only applies to MY element and not to the generated fancybox code.

Is there any way I can get control of particular instances of the generated code?

I'm aware of the wrapCSS property but, as I see it, that will put a containing class round ALL the images and not just specified ones... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Janis for pointing me in the right direction!

Using the following code attached to the **beforeShow** event I was able to get to an acceptable effect...

```
        $('#gallery a').fancybox({          
        beforeShow: function () {
            if ($(this.element).hasClass('flag')) {
                this.skin.css("background-color", "green");                
            }
        }, ...etc...
```

The main problem I was having was being able to get at properties of the current element which

```
$(this.element)
```

allowed me to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callbacks to style based on current item. For example:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {

        if (this.index == 0) {
            this.skin.css("background-color", "green");

        } else if (this.index == 1) {
            this.skin.css("background-color", "blue");
        }

    }
});​
```

See in action - http://jsfiddle.net/LehkV/

There are different ways to set parameters individually, see #15 from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, however the first method doesn't really do what I want... I want to state in the HTML that a particular effect is to be used, for example, by a class.  That way it's easy for me to add images and mark them as required on the various pages where this is used.  The method shown above has inbuilt knowledge of the images, i.e. make the first one green, etc...

#15 from the tips and tricks does look promising and maybe I can use it with the hasClass function.

Comment: That was just an example, it is up to you how you organize your code. There are tons of possible scenarios, for example, you could store color as "data" attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/brq5b/